# Online schema changes for cloudsql DB

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, ddl, google-cloud-sql, online-operations

I'm new to cloudsql for mysql. I have a table with trigger. I need to do some ddl changes on that table. However, I can't take any downtime.

**What I have tried so far:**

I tried with pt-online-schema-change. Because, it work for our local databases. However, in case of managed cloudsql - it wasn't working. Opened an issue with Percona(PT-1964).

Next, I checked for gh-ost. However, as per their documentation(https://github.com/github/gh-ost/blob/master/doc/requirements-and-limitations.md) -it doesn't support any table with trigger.

Making changes with shared lock option isn't available for me - because we have a replica too.

Does anyone knows any other method/suggeation to make ddl changes online for cloudsql for mysql.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the change?  There could be a workaround.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames for response. There are two changes - index addition and column alteration(adding enum value)

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY COLUMN c ENUM(...) ...
```

If that is only adding a new option *on the end* and not going past 255 options, that should be a "schema-only" change that happens instantly.  (This was in 5.5, so has been around for 12 years.)

Any other change to the `ENUM` is likely to require a "copy" of the table (slow).

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD INDEX (...)
```

has been efficient (not instant, but did not require copying the table over) since 5.6 (2013).

For other column alterations -- It depends.

That probably does not apply to `ADD UNIQUE`, and certainly does not apply to any changes to the `PRIMARY KEY`.

So, based on that info, I would *expect* Cloud-SQL with 5.7 to handle things "fast".  (Sorry, but I have no direct knowledge of that port of MySQL.)  I suggest you take it up with the vendor.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Rick . What I understood from your answer - that I can run enum modification without any of these kind of tool(since it's not going to lock the table) ..my table size is 150GB

Comment: @ShiwanginiShishulkar - Correct; just do the `ALTER`.  Read the 5.7 manual; it spells things out.  ALTER has changed a lot, and frequently, since 5.6; I can't keep all the details in my head.

Comment: Thanks @Rick - I was able to add enum value without any locking directly.